# Não consigo remover a barra de títulos da aplicação android

Tags: java, android

Já tentei utilizando `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`, mas quando executo meu app ele dá erro.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e cole o stack trace do erro e, se possível, adicione também classe onde o erro ocorre.

Answer (score 4):

Temos muitas maneiras de fazer isso. Uma delas é por código, basta adicionarmos a seguinte linha no método `onCreate`:

```java
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Ficando assim:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}
```

Também é possível remover a barra de títulos pelo arquivo “`AndroidManifest.xml`”. Para isso devemos modificar a declaração da Activity para declarar que não queremos a barra.
Basta acrescentar/modificar o atributo “`android:theme`” na declaração da Activity, dessa forma:

```xml
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Para que todas as Activities de sua aplicação fique sem a barra de títutlo, modifique o mesmo atributo, porém na “Application”:

```xml
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Com a complexidade dos aplicativos que desenvolvemos hoje, não é incomum trabalhar com temas, o que facilita bastante o nosso trabalho. Caso você já trabalhe assim e não quer ficar adicionando os códigos para remoção em todas as suas classes basta modificar seu tema e colocar o atributo “`android:windowsNoTitle`” como `true`.

Veja o exemplo:

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Fonte: http://www.henriquelacerda.com.br/2014/06/20/removendo-barra-de-titulo-aplicativo-android/

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Arrumei a formatação para você. :)

Comment: @Victor vlw! :)

Answer (score 0):

É simples, só adicionar uma linha de código ao onCreate.

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //Esta linha contém o código necessário.
    setContentView(R.layout.sua_activity);
}
```